# Outlook Desktop Background Images

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

Is there any WORKING example of an email that will show a background image?

Even "bulletproof" `VML` solutions won't really work, ex:

- https://codepen.io/palak-tal/pen/eYWggYa
- [How make background image on newsletter in outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970143/how-make-background-image-on-newsletter-in-outlook/13259519#13259519)

Tried, VML, `img` tags, background images on different tags, `svg`, nothing seems to really work for Outlook Desktop.

For the record, background images will work anywhere but Outloook Desktop client (gmail, outlook web/mobile, etc).

Thanks.

Comment: I recently answered this one, which works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797674/email-template-background-image-with-text-overlay-at-center-location/71822661?noredirect=1#comment126921553_71822661

Comment: This one seems to work too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30731838/8942566

Comment: First one is actually working (second one won't), if you answer the question I can set yours as correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, it only seems to work if you wait a couple of seconds, right click the image, and only then it will display it. Quite odd.

Comment: That particular image on that answer is quite large--i.e. takes a while to download. If you have an optimised image with a good CDN, it will appear faster.

Comment: The normal thing to do here would be to label this as a duplicate, so I'll do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Email template - Background image with text overlay at Center location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797674/email-template-background-image-with-text-overlay-at-center-location)

Comment: @Nathan: Partially. We gave up on this and used traditional emails with no background images. Even your examples (which were the best I could get :) so thanks and kudos) won't display the image immediately. It needs a couple of seconds, then a click on the email and they'll appear (even sometimes they won't even appear after this, even using other small images from othe CDNs).

Answer (score 0):

Word renders HTML images in Outlook, and it does not support background images for the `body` HTML element.  Try to create a table that takes the whole client area and specify a background image for that table.

Comment: This is not correct. You can use VML

Comment: @Nathan It is absolutely correct. Word does not support background-image on the body element.

Comment: Ah well, choice of words. Eugene is correct, and that might be what you are trying to say. But, I read what you have written as "Outlook does not support background images (at all)" - when in fact, with VML, it does.

Answer (score 0):

The `background-image` CSS property is not supported by the Word editor in Outlook. You can read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Comment: In other words, use VML